# Are there any advantages to having SQL hosting separate from a website? Hosting my own servers or paying for a service?

Tags: performance, database-design

### Background

I have been tinkering with an application I am writing. It is essentially a POS system that stores information about customers and inventory. Currently I keep all the data stored in CSVs while I develop the GUI, classes, etc.; however, I have always envisioned needing a SQL server at some point. Additionally, farther down the line I might end up buying a domain and having my own website, but I may use something that has free hosting since I only expect there to be one page.

Quick aside, I am aware plain-text CSVs are not secure and I am not storing real peoples' info in them.

I have been curious to try hosting my own database (and possibly a web server). Currently, I cannot see my database exceeding a hundred real entries, but I do occasionally test with sample CSVs that are 20k. Obviously, I should keep in mind scalability.

I'm currently on Windows, but I used to feel at home in a BASH terminal if that makes any difference.

### Questions

Anyways, I suppose my questions are as follows:

What are the benefits of hosting your own database?

Is there any benefits of hosting your database on a separate server from your web server, e.g.MySQL hosting on Scale Grid then eventually a web server on BlueHost?

Are there any advantages to hosting an SQL server on your own? I'm literally imagining a spare laptop, or building a small custom PC with a RAID setup. Although, a laptop with all the necessary files on a cloud back up such as OneDrive seems feasible.

Anyways, I am not necessarily looking for a direct answer. I am just hoping you all will share your experiences and thoughts.

*Apologies if this on the wrong exchange, this is a bit of an open ended question and this one seemed like a good fit!*

Answer (score 1):

What are the benefits of hosting your own database?
If you mean make your database in cloud hosting, the benefit is you don't have to install configure your database system (like DBA did)

Is there any benefits of hosting your database on a separate server from your web server, e.g.MySQL hosting on Scale Grid then eventually a web server on BlueHost?

- easier to scaling your database
  Imagine you hosting your application in web hosting and currently your traffic is low and then couple days your traffic is gain 100x than before. You can't do anything for scale your database (web hosting haven't feature database scaling)

Are there any advantages to hosting an SQL server on your own? I'm literally imagining a spare laptop, or building a small custom PC with a RAID setup. Although, a laptop with all the necessary files on a cloud back up such as OneDrive seems feasible.
Your scalability limited on your current hardware. If you already use your hardware spesification, you can't scale it more.

The last, everything is based on your needs. If your traffic is low you can use web hosting first and then migrate to vm/cloud/etc (saving cost)
if money dont matter you can choose cloud